# How to return response from an api in 2 seconds which depends on multiple services?

Tags: rest, system-design

I recently came across an interview question:

Suppose you have to maintain SLA for an api to return response in 2 seconds. It depends on 3 services each of which return response in 1 second. Output of first is input for 2nd and output of 2nd is input of 3rd. How can we return response from our API in 2 seconds.

One of the solutions that came to my mind was to maintain cache for each service which can be asynchronously updated. Is there a better solution? More importantly is this a valid question?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what programming languages you're using. Technically, in nodejs you're able to make asynchronous request to 3 different services.

If any of these services are dependent each other's response, the async option I mentioned above does not work.

Getting data from these services into your environment will help your SLA, because in real-time you're not dependent any of these 3 services. Here is the catch. How do you make sure that the data is out-of-sync?  You might end up another issue to solve. Not sure about the size of data. You might end up additional cost too.